# Lógica matemática apostando na loteria

Tags: matemática, lógica, pseudocódigo

Não consigo pensar na **lógica matemática** da seguinte questão:

Três amigos jogaram na loteria. Caso eles ganhem, o prêmio deve ser repartido proporcionalmente ao valor que cada um deu para a realização da aposta.

> O objetivo é fazer um programa que leia o valor que cada apostador investiu e o valor do premio e no fim, informar quanto cada apostador ganharia do prêmio com base no valor investido.

Pra facilitar eu tenho apenas o esboço do pseudocódigo.

```
float aposta1, aposta2, aposta3, premio, recebe1, recebe2, recebe3;
leia aposta1, aposta2, aposta3, premio;
```

A grande dificuldade pra mim se deve ao fato de não haver um intervalo pré-definido de valores para aposta, tornando assim difícil a criação do algoritmo.

> No algoritmo devo usar preferivelmente conteúdo bem básico de programação, se possível até mesmo sem condicionais.

Comment: Se você pegar o quanto corresponde em porcentagem de cada aposta e no final, o premio ser com base na mesma porcentagem, resolve?

Comment: apostatotal = (aposta1 + aposta2 + aposta3); aposta1 é quantos porcento de (apostatotal) ; aposta2 é quantos porcento de (apostatotal); aposta3 é quantos porcento de (apostatotal); receber1 = %aposta1 sobre o premio; receber2=%aposta2 sobre o premio; receber3=%aposta3 sobre o premio; Fiz um PHP para testar a lógica https://ideone.com/MR4Me4

Comment: Exato @LeoCaracciolo. Essa é a forma fácil de ser feito isso. Algo que nem fui capaz de pensar naquele momento kkkk. Anyway, no código que você fez, você usou regra de três para achar a porcentagem de cada aposta, apenas um pouco diferente do que pensei agora pouco, mas que, de qualquer maneira, chega se a resolução do problema descrito. Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com base nas respostas de @David Dias e @Leo Caracciolo, chego a simples conclusão que uma boa solução é fazer o seguinte:

Faça a soma de todos os valores apostados, na forma:

```
apostaTotal = aposta1 + aposta2 + aposta3;
```

E para achar a porcentagem correspondente, simplesmente deve se fazer a divisão da aposta pelo valor total da aposta. Exemplo:

```
porcentagem1 = aposta1 / apostaTotal;
```

E depois, para ter o valor individual do prêmio é só multiplicar o valor do prêmio pela porcentagem investida de cada apostador.

Abaixo segue a resolução da pergunta com um exemplo de código escrito na linguagem C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    float aposta1, aposta2, aposta3, premio, p1, p2, p3, apostaTotal, recebe1, recebe2, recebe3;
    scanf("%f%f%f%f",&aposta1, &aposta2, &aposta3, &premio);

    apostaTotal = aposta1 + aposta2 + aposta3;
    p1 = aposta1 / apostaTotal;
    p2 = aposta2 / apostaTotal;
    p3 = aposta3 / apostaTotal;

    recebe1 = premio * p1;
    recebe2 = premio * p2;
    recebe3 = premio * p3;

    printf("\nO apostador 1 recebe: %f\n", recebe1);
    printf("O apostador 2 recebe: %f\n", recebe2);
    printf("O apostador 3 recebe: %f\n", recebe3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exatamente , você simplificou as etapas na matemática. Eu fiz passo a passo para melhor entendimento. Mas poderia simplificar mais ainda veja recebe1 = (premio * aposta1)/apostaTotal; evitando as linhas p1, p2, p3  Veja com PHP no Ideone https://ideone.com/1GNoxD

Answer (score 1):

Ficaria assim sem pseudo código.

```
  var Premio, Apostador01, Apostador02, Apostador01, ApostadorPc01, ApostadorPc02,ApostadorPc03: float;
  leia  Premio
  leia  Apostador01;
  leia  Apostador02;
  leia  Apostador03;
  Aposta := Apostador01+Apostador02+Apostador03;

  ApostadorPc01  := (Apostador01.Value*100)/Aposta;
  ApostadorPc02  := (Apostador02.Value*100)/Aposta;
  ApostadorPc03  := (Apostador03.Value*100)/Aposta;

  Escreva 'porcentagem do Apostador1'+ ApostadorPc01  +'%';
  Escreva 'porcentagem do Apostador2'+ ApostadorPc02  +'%';
  Escreva 'porcentagem do Apostador3'+ ApostadorPc03  +'%';

  Escreva 'Premio do Apostador1'+ ((Premio*ApostadorPc01)/100);
  Escreva 'Premio do Apostador2'+ ((Premio*ApostadorPc02)/100);
  Escreva 'Premio do Apostador3'+ ((Premio*ApostadorPc03)/100);
```